# Could you recreate the 3D page turning effect seen in the iBooks app using only Core Animation or would you need to use OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, core-animation

I read an article somewhere explaining that apple uses OpenGL ES to implement [the page turning effect in the iBooks app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=832uNh7_0Vo).  Since you can perform 3D animations on 2D Layers using only Core Animation, what might be some reasons you'd have to use OpenGL ES to create that page transition animation?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steven Troughton-Smith has accomplished this here without OpenGL. http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html

However, he uses Private APIs, so you may want to be careful.